# How to decide where to put property in for beginner in CSS?

Tags: html, css, web, typesetting

I'm new to CSS. Some problems of the place for the property happened after getting familiar with CSS. Like this:

[image]
P1: check`#menu` & `#menu a`
[code is here](http://jsbin.com/zupape/1/edit?html,css,output)

[image]
P2: check `#menu a`
[code is here](http://jsbin.com/duvulo/1/edit?html,css,output)

It seems to be the same result for different places of property like `float: right`, `position: relative`, etc. either in `#menu{ }` and `#menu a{ }`...

Now I'm pretty confused that when and how to decide where to put those properties in the correct place? Can anyone give me some basic idea? :)

Comment: Post some code, not screenshot. Throw it all in a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) while you're at it.

Comment: Could you please explain what you are trying to ask? I can't quite follow.

Comment: Sorry guys. I'm new to here and tried my best to describe. Now codes are on. Please take a view.

Answer (score 1):

In your above example you should apply it to the anchor tag, as you'll want it to be used as a button.

If you apply those styles to the div, then you'll need to `display: block;` on the anchor.

You should almost always apply the css to the exact element you're trying to style.

Comment: So it's highly recommended to put styles to the right element? OK, I'll notice it in the future. Sometimes, I feel some tutorial videos add elements in the parent and some in the child. It's hard to know when to put elements in...

Answer (score 1):

Try this i have simplified your code, as a beginner you can get familiar in css by the best practice only ...

```css
body { 
    font-family: 'myriad pro', helvetica, sans-serif;
    color: #444;
}
a {
    color: #444;
    text-decoration: none;
}
#header {
    float: left;
    width: 96%;/*if you use box-sizing you can put 100% */
    padding: 2%;
}
#logo {
    float: left;
}
#logo h1 {
    margin: 0;
}
#logo h1 span {
    font-weight: normal;
}
#menu {
    float: right;
    margin: 0;
    list-style: none;
}
#menu a {
    border-radius: 25px;
    display: block;
    border: solid 2px #444;
    padding: 5px 20px;
    line-height: 24px;
}
#menu a:hover {
   background: #444;
   color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div id="header">
    <div id="logo">
        <h1><span>d</span>tech</h1>
    </div>
    <ul id="menu">
        <li><a href="#"><span>Get in touch</span></a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Karthi!!! I was wondering how professional engineer do with this. I'll try my best to do it!:D